# Google Chrome password management for complex credentials

Tags: google-chrome, password-management

I use a bunch of web sites which contain sensitive data -- or at least that's what they think, and I don't necessarily think so. Those web sites often require you to enter a username, an account ID and a password, so they no longer match Chrome's idea of username/password.

What is a good Google Chrome extension to remember passwords for those sites?

Comment: I might be possible to use a username/password combo, and autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/). It has [a Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd) and it's free.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Mac, [1Password](https://agilebits.com/products/1password) is great! It has a 30 day trial, and the single user license is $69.99.

[image]

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.